# How to make audio/video calls and get the call type in on_incoming_call function in PJSIP in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pjsip

I built PJSIP library with PJSUA_HAS_VIDEO as 1. I want to make an option to make audio only calls. I tried

```
pjsua_call_setting opt;
pjsua_call_setting_default(&opt);
opt.flag = PJSUA_CALL_INCLUDE_DISABLED_MEDIA;
opt.vid_cnt = 0;
opt.aud_cnt = 1;
pj_status_t status = pjsua_call_make_call((pjsua_acc_id)[self identifier], &uri, &opt, NULL, NULL, &callIdentifier);
```

At the receiving end, in `on_incoming_call()` function, I tried

```
if (callInfo.rem_offerer && callInfo.rem_vid_cnt == 1)
    {
        call.hasVideo = YES;
    } else {
        call.hasVideo = NO;
    }
```

But `rem_vid_cnt` is always giving 1.
How can I set the call type while making call and receive it correctly at receiving end? I want to set the `setHasVideo` field of CallKit also at receiving end.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At the app end your code is correct.

You need to disable video from server side also.

Comment: What type of setting needed from server side?

Answer (score 0):

This is a two way communication. You can do this from the caller side set the rem_vid_cnt = 0 when you initiate a call, and at the receiver side you will get this as "0".

Hope this will help you :)

> /** Number of video streams offered by remote */
>
> unsigned      rem_vid_cnt;